# VBA Insert cell contents into header

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help with VBA in Excel. I have a workbook with 20+ sheets. I need to take the contents of a cell from the first sheet, format the font and add it to the header to most, but not all of the sheets within the same workbook. I'm new to VBA, so any help would be much appreciated. Thank you! Cheryl

Comment: Please see how to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be more specific with your question - for example, how will you determine how many sheets contain the data? Do you mean the actual header of the sheet (in a technical sense) as the header is standardized across all sheets, not some or most? Give us an example of the cell data, and an example or what output you'd like to see, and we'll do our best!